# Why Dialog is not a Component in Scala Swing?

Tags: events, scala, dialog

This question arises because I want to capture `LostFocusEvent` from `Dialog`. Unfortunately, this event is not fired for non `Component` derived components. What I want to ask is what is the aim of `Dialog` not derived from Component, but `RichWindow`, as compared to the Swing library?

Answer (score 1):

I think really the best way to get the answer is to contact [Ingo Maier](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/) directly, but you may be able to deduce the some of the thinking behind from his blog article [The scala.swing package in 2.8 and beyond](http://ingomaier.blogspot.com/2010/11/scalaswing-package-in-28-and-beyond.html):

> ### Window hierarchy
>
> This is how the Java AWT/Swing window hierarchy looks like:
>
> [image: AWT/Swing window hierarchy]
>
> While AWT's `Frame` and `Dialog` share the common base class `Window`, the Swing extensions have no subclass relationship or extend a common interface even though they share common functionality not present in AWT. In an attempt to straighten things up a little, we redesigned the window base hierarchy in scala.swing which now looks as follows:
>
> [image: scala.swing hierarchy]
>
> [...]
>
> This design lets us factor common wrapper code into class `RichWindow`.

So I am guessing that this is a deliberate design by the author stating that Windows are in fact not *components* in the same way frames and buttons are, and can be dropped on to other containers.